# WSO2 API Manager Generating Key error using external LDAP

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I added an external LDAP to WSO2 API  Manager v1.9.  When I log in to the API Store with a user from the external LDAP (internal LDAP that comes with WSO2 works fine) I get an error when I try to generate an OAuth2.0 Key from the My Subscriptions page.  The error is a pop-up window that says "Error occurred while executing the action generateApplicationKey".

Is there something else I need to set for using an external LDAP?

ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjecgts.APIStoreHostObject} - Error while obtaining the application access token for the application:itest {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjecgts.APIStoreHostObject} org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Error occurred while Creating Keys.
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIUtil.handleException(APIUtil.java:1117)
....

Comment: Can you post the exeption trace here. You can find the log file in <APIM_HOME>/repository/logs directory.

Comment: I added the trace to the original question above. Its long, so hopefully I provided enough info to help debug it.

Comment: Provided trace is not enough to find the issue. Can you provide the full one please. (probably host it somewhere and give the link). Another thing, API manager does not come with internal LDAP. It has JDBC user store.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38255418/wso2-am-1-10-0-api-store-error-occurred-while-executing-the-action-generateapp (this is with extermal saml2 IdP)